Is there any way to read the data in STC11F02E?
I need to read the data from the STC11F02E microcontroller. Is there a way to do this?

https://github.com/grigorig/stcgal is an open-source ISP tool for STC microcontrollers. Officially it only supports flash writing and erasing, but perhaps the underlying protocol also supports reading.
